# Slick: Odd error when using .firstOption.get | [SlickException: Read NULL value (null) for ResultSet column Path s2._5]

Tags: slick

So I have the following code used as a validation method:

```
  if (TableQuery[UsersTable].filter(_.name === login).exists.run) {
    val id = TableQuery[UsersTable].filter(_.name === login).firstOption.get.id
    val name = TableQuery[UsersTable].filter(_.id === id).firstOption.get.name
  }
```

if you're wondering, I check to make sure of .exists before I query the next two times because the login value can be equal to two columns in the database.

Anyways, I get [SlickException: Read NULL value (null) for ResultSet column Path s2._5] when attempting to get the id above, and I'm unsure why. There should be a first option there because the code has already validated a row exists for the requirements typed beforehand. No "id" column values are null.

How can I get this id value working correctly?

Comment: Is one of the involved columns nullable but you didn't specify it as Option[...] in the Table?

Comment: Ah. That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One of the involved columns is nullable but you didn't specify it as Option[...] in the Table.